# Dynamic Slide in Ionic Using <ion-slides>

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slide-box

I cant find any dynamic slide by using **ion-slides**, Most of them given by **ion-slide-box** which is going deprecated, I used **ion-slides** for creating dynamic pager but I cant achieved,Swipe is not working only first card is displayed,I am beginner in ionic any idea...

my Html code:

```
 <ion-slides  pager loop="true" options="swiperOptions"> 
      <ion-slide-page  ng-repeat="employe in employees">
                  <h1>{{employe.firstname}}</h1>
                  <p>{{employe.gender}}
      </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```

my js controller:

```
.controller("mytestcontroller",function ($scope){
          var employees = [
                    {
                      firstname : "Baskar",
                      lastname : "Risk",
                      gender : "Male",
                      url: " "
                       },
                       {
                      firstname : "Ram",
                      lastname : "Risk",
                      gender : "Male",
                      url: ""
                      },{
                      firstname : "Kumar",
                      lastname : "Risk",
                      gender : "Male",
                      url: ""
                      }];
          $scope.employees=employees;
      })
```

Comment: Did you find any solution.. ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you associated your 'mytestcontroller' in your html like eg.:

```
<body ng-controller="mytestcontroller">
```